# Cannot run spark jobs locally using sbt, but works in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I've written a few simple Spark jobs and some tests for them. I've done everything in IntelliJ and it works great. Now, I'd like to make sure my code builds with `sbt`. Compiling is fine, but I get strange errors during running and testing.

I am using Scala version `2.11.8` and `sbt` version `0.13.8`

My `build.sbt` file looks like this:

```
name := "test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "javax.mail" % "javax.mail-api" % "1.5.6"
libraryDependencies += "com.sun.mail" % "javax.mail" % "1.5.6"
libraryDependencies += "commons-cli" % "commons-cli" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "3.0.0" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "com.holdenkarau" % "spark-testing-base_2.11" % "2.0.0_0.4.4" % "test" intransitive()
```

I try to run my code using `sbt "run-main com.test.email.processor.bin.Runner"` Here is the output:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/max/workplace/test/project
[info] Set current project to test (in build file:/Users/max/workplace/test/)
[info] Running com.test.email.processor.bin.Runner -j recipientCount -e /Users/max/workplace/data/test/enron_with_categories/*/*.txt
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/08/23 18:46:55 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.0.0
16/08/23 18:46:55 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/08/23 18:46:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: max
16/08/23 18:46:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: max
16/08/23 18:46:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/08/23 18:46:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/08/23 18:46:55 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(max); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(max); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/08/23 18:46:56 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 61759.
16/08/23 18:46:56 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/08/23 18:46:56 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/08/23 18:46:56 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/75/4dydy_6110v0gjv7bg265_g40000gn/T/blockmgr-9eb526c0-b7e5-444a-b186-d7f248c5dc62
16/08/23 18:46:56 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 408.9 MB
16/08/23 18:46:56 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/08/23 18:46:56 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/08/23 18:46:56 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.1.11:4040
16/08/23 18:46:56 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
16/08/23 18:46:57 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 61760.
16/08/23 18:46:57 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.1.11:61760
16/08/23 18:46:57 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.11, 61760)
16/08/23 18:46:57 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.1.11:61760 with 408.9 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.11, 61760)
16/08/23 18:46:57 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.11, 61760)
16/08/23 18:46:57 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 128.0 KB, free 408.8 MB)
16/08/23 18:46:57 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 14.6 KB, free 408.8 MB)
16/08/23 18:46:57 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.11:61760 (size: 14.6 KB, free: 408.9 MB)
16/08/23 18:46:57 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from wholeTextFiles at RecipientCountJob.scala:22
16/08/23 18:46:58 WARN ClosureCleaner: Expected a closure; got com.test.email.processor.util.cleanEmail$
16/08/23 18:46:58 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1702
16/08/23 18:46:58 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1702
16/08/23 18:46:58 INFO CombineFileInputFormat: DEBUG: Terminated node allocation with : CompletedNodes: 1, size left: 0
16/08/23 18:46:58 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: take at RecipientCountJob.scala:35
16/08/23 18:46:58 WARN DAGScheduler: Creating new stage failed due to exception - job: 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function0
    at sbt.classpath.ClasspathFilter.loadClass(ClassLoaders.scala:63)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.twitter.chill.KryoBase$$anonfun$1.apply(KryoBase.scala:41)
    at com.twitter.chill.KryoBase$$anonfun$1.apply(KryoBase.scala:41)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:166)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at com.twitter.chill.KryoBase.<init>(KryoBase.scala:41)
    at com.twitter.chill.EmptyScalaKryoInstantiator.newKryo(ScalaKryoInstantiator.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.borrowKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.<init>(KryoSerializer.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newInstance(KryoSerializer.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.supportsRelocationOfSerializedObjects$lzycompute(KryoSerializer.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.supportsRelocationOfSerializedObjects(KryoSerializer.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleManager$.canUseSerializedShuffle(SortShuffleManager.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleManager.registerShuffle(SortShuffleManager.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.ShuffleDependency.<init>(Dependency.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.getDependencies(ShuffledRDD.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$dependencies$2.apply(RDD.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$dependencies$2.apply(RDD.scala:233)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.dependencies(RDD.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.visit$2(DAGScheduler.scala:418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.getAncestorShuffleDependencies(DAGScheduler.scala:433)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getShuffleMapStage(DAGScheduler.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$visit$1$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:394)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$visit$1$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:391)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.visit$1(DAGScheduler.scala:391)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.getParentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.getParentStagesAndId(DAGScheduler.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.newResultStage(DAGScheduler.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1626)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
16/08/23 18:46:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: take at RecipientCountJob.scala:35, took 0.076653 s
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:runMain for the full output.
16/08/23 18:46:58 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error in cleaning thread
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1229)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$1.run(ContextCleaner.scala:67)
16/08/23 18:46:58 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread SparkListenerBus, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:66)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:64)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
```

Comment: Do you have Scala 2.11 installed?

Comment: I do have it installed, but how do I let sbt know where it is?

Comment: As long as SCALA_HOME is set, you're good

Comment: But I thought sbt was responsible for installing Scala

Comment: Setting SCALA_HOME had no effect

Comment: Which Java version are you working with?

Comment: Java version is 1.8.0u74

Comment: Both in your dev environment and locally in Intellij?

Comment: did you try to run this interactively? First run `sbt` then type `run` then select the main you want to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Spark cannot be run via `sbt`. I ended up packing the entire job into a jar using the `assembly` plugin and running it with `java`.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you are missing your scala-library as `scala.Function0` comes from the standard Scala lib.

You could try adding the scala-lib in certain scopes

`libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.value`

But it seems like the scala-lib is not being added to the classpath of your run.

Might want to also add something like so the same classpath used to compile is used to run the code in SBT.

`fullClasspath in run := (fullClasspath in Compile).value`

Comment: Seems unlikely that the scala-library isn't on the classpath. Also, adding both lines did nothing. Is it possible the Spark tasks aren't getting the correct class path?